# CSS and JS files doesn't load on server | Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, web, hosting

few days ago I created a Laravel project to do some tests. Everything has gone perfect but when I wanted to try it on a hosting the files css and js of the page does not load.
They all return the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

The page loads but without styles.

All my css and js files are referred with the laravel's asset helper like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("styles/css/bootstrap.min.css")}}">
```

Does somebody know anything about this?

Comment: Are these files located in the `/public folder`?

Comment: Of course, as I say in local mode it works perfectly

Comment: This works when using `php artisan serve`. But upon hosting it using nginx or apache, or any other webserver it fails?

Comment: Try to use your chrome' elements, and post what the complete url of this link is, that will be helpful